# Entity Framework and copying 100 rows at the time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, service-worker

I'm writing my first Service Worker to handle copying all records from one table to another every 60 seconds. At the moment everything works like a charm, but after deploying I wan't to make sure that all future data will be copied 100 records at one time, until no more records left to copy - and than 60 seconds break.

Fallowing code will copy every record from given date at once, and than wait 60 seconds.

```
 public void CopyLatestData(DateTime from)
    {
        using (var context = new EdDbContext())
        {
            var dataToCopy = context.ELMAH_Errors.Where(x => x.TimeUtc > from).ToList();

            var result = dataToCopy.Select(x => new parsed_errors(x)).ToList();

            context.parsed_errors.AddRange(result);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This is how I handle timer

```
  private static void startTimer()
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 60 * 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += timer_ElapsedActions;
            timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private static void timer_ElapsedActions(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isTaskAlreadyRunning)
        {
            return;
        }
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (!isTaskAlreadyRunning)
            {
                isTaskAlreadyRunning = true;
                try
                {
                    copyDataFromRemoteDatabaseToLocalDatabase();
                    parseCopiedData();                      
                }
                finally
                {
                    isTaskAlreadyRunning = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

what is the easiest way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion would be add a boolean in your Entity like `AlreadyCopied` or `IsCopied`. Then use that as a marker.

```
public bool CopyLatestData()
{
    using (var context = new EdDbContext())
    {
        var query = context.ELMAH_Errors.Where(x => !x.IsCopied).AsQueryable();
        //if (query.Any())
        if (query.Count() != 0) //this will check if some are left not copied
        {
            var dataToCopy = query.Take(100).ToList(); //this will only take the first 100
            var result = dataToCopy.Select(x => new parsed_errors(x)).ToList();

            context.parsed_errors.AddRange(result);
            dataToCopy.ForEach(x => x.IsCopied = true); //this will update the records to IsCopied = true
            context.SaveChanges();
            if (query.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

then in your timer stop timer if the bool value of the `if (Copylatestdata() == false)`

```
private static void timer_ElapsedActions(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var stillHasRecords = CopyLatestData();
    if (!stillHasRecords)
    {
        Timer timer = (Timer)sender; //get the sender object
        timer.Stop(); // stop the sender
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using .Take() to limit the number of rows returned by the query, that way every 60 seconds it will return a maximum of 100 records. If fewer than 100 records are present it will only return what is there.

```
var dataToCopy = context.ELMAH_Errors.Where(x => x.TimeUtc > from).Take(100).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to 'IsProcessed' would be to keep 'latestProcessed' and then retrieve records that have timestamps after that, in batches of 100.

(Something like the code below, sorry for bad formatting, I'm typing on a phone)

```
while( keepGoing) {
var dataToCopy = context.ELMAH_Errors
       .Where(x => x.TimeUtc > from)
       .Where(x => x.TimeUTc > lastProcessedUtc)
       .Take(100)
       .OrderBy( x => x.TimeUtc)
       .ToList();

(...)
if( dataToCopy.Any() ) lastProcessedUtc = data.Last().TimeUtc;
keepGoing = dataToCopy.Any(); //Or .Count()  == 100
```